# Set mailroot directories for IIS SMTP

Tags: iis, smtp

Using IIS 7.5 on Windows Server 2008 R2

I need to change the default location for ALL SMTP directories (default locations shown below):

```
C:\inetpub\mailroot\Badmail
C:\inetpub\mailroot\Drop
C:\inetpub\mailroot\Pickup
C:\inetpub\mailroot\Queue
```

to the following:

```
D:\smtp\badmail
D:\smtp\drop
D:\smtp\pickup
D:\smtp\queue
```

The ONLY directory which is configurable via Start -> Administrative Tools -> Internet Information Services IIS (6.0) Manager is the "Badmail" directory -- a new directory can be entered directly using the IIS (6.0) Manager.

No other option is available for the other 3 directories.

Is there any way to change these directories WITHOUT:
a) Having to install adsutil.vbs?

Is it possible to change these via Powershell?

Did I miss something or some other utility that can do this?

Any help/advice would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I going to try to answer my own question... Can anyone (Microsoft) verify if this is correct before I try this little plan?

1. Start -> Administrative Tools -> Internet Information Services IIS (6.0) Manager
2. Right-click on sever name and select "Properties"
3. Check box labeled "Enable Direct Metabase Edit" -> Click OK
4. Stop the SMTP site.
5. Using NotePad, open the MetBase file located at C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\MetaBase.xml
6. Update the locations for the "Badmail", "Drop", "Pickup" and "Queue" directories.  Save file.
7. Start the SMTP site.

From this point forward, the new directories should be used -- correct?

Comment: 1, 2, 3, 4, 7 aren't necessary. 

`iisreset -stop`, edit file, `iisreset -start` should do. (Just performed on Server 2016)

Comment: @mtnielsen so long as you don't have active websites that you don't want to restart at the moment.

Comment: @BVernon Yes, if you run websites on your mail relay they too will be affected by a general iisreset -stop.

Comment: This seems to revert the path changes back in MetaBase.xml once the SMTP server is started again

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find that the accepted answer worked for me in IIS 8.5 Windows Server 2012 R2, but I did find a solution that worked. It requires using the adsutil.vbs that gets installed if you add the feature under the add roles or features wizard - features - management tools - iis6 management compatibility - iis6 scripting tools:

ref. https://www.itnota.com/moving-default-smtp-folders-to-different-drive-windows-server/

Launch Command Prompt (Admin) and run these commands:

```
net stop smtpsvc
set util=C:\inetpub\AdminScripts\adsutil.vbs
set dst=D:\smtp\
robocopy c:\inetpub\mailroot %dst% /e /copyall /dcopy:T /move
cscript.exe %util% set smtpsvc/1/badmaildirectory %dst%Badmail
cscript.exe %util% set smtpsvc/1/dropdirectory %dst%Drop
cscript.exe %util% set smtpsvc/1/pickupdirectory %dst%Pickup
cscript.exe %util% set smtpsvc/1/queuedirectory %dst%Queue
net start smtpsvc
```

This only moves folders and sets paths for the first SMTP virtual server. For others, change "smtpsvc/1/" to "smtpsvc/2/", and possibly comment out the robocopy depending on how your paths were configured for the other smtp virtual servers.